# Javascript regex only alphabet, number and underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a text box input is valid (only alphabet, numbers and underscores allowed. No whitespaces or dashes). I currently have this, but whitespaces & dashes seem to pass.

```
function validText(field)
{
    var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]$/
    if (field.value.search(re) == -1)
    {
        alert ("Invalid Text");
        return false;
    }
}
```

A valid input would be something like

'`Valid_Input123`'

invalid

```
'Invalid-Input !'
```

Comment: Tip: `[a-zA-Z0-9_] == \w`

Comment: Well, maybe dashes pass because you included a dash character.

Comment: it is not a dash character, it means all letters from a to z

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. The `\w` is a handy regex escape sequence that covers letters, numbers and the underscore character
2. You should test the entire string for valid characters by anchoring the validity test at the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the expression
3. The regular expression `test` method is faster than the string `search` method
4. You can also test for one or more characters using the `+` quantifier

To summarise (in code)

```
var re = /^\w+$/;
if (!re.test(field.value)) {
    alert('Invalid Text');
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Alternatively, you can test for any invalid characters using

```
/\W/.test(field.value)
```

`\W` being any character **other than** letters, numbers or the underscore character.

Then you might also need to add a length check to invalidate empty strings, eg

```
if (/\W/.test(field.value) || field.value.length === 0)
```

Comment: OP also specified a hyphen in his character class

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis OP also says (and I quote) *"only alphabet, numbers and underscores allowed. No whitespaces or **dashes**"*

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis And yet that goes against the rest of the post: `only alphabet, numbers and underscores allowed. No whitespaces or dashes`

Comment: @Phil This answer would be better with an explanation.

Comment: @Daedalus I agree, but Felix types faster than I do

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just looked at the hyphen and didn't realize it could be an accident. Oops

Comment: @Daedalus Explanation added

Answer (score 13):

You are only testing whether the text **ends** (`$`) with one of the characters in the character class. You are also explicitly allowing a dash (`\-`). If you don't want that, remove it.

Anchor the expression (`^`, `$`), add a quantifier (`+`) and [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) whether the string only consists of those characters:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/; // or /^\w+$/ as mentioned
if (!re.test(field.value)) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`[\w]*` will suffice.

[Regex101 Example](http://regex101.com/r/fI9hJ4)

---

**This is a very basic Regular Expressions question**

Learn more about regular expressions here: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 4):

1. You forgot to anchor your regex at the beginning using `^`
2. `test` is easier to use
3. There is no need for the dash.

It should look like this:

```
if (!/^[a-z0-9_]+$/i.test(field.value)) {
    //
}
```